# Papyrus: Exception after applying CSS to model

Tags: css, eclipse, uml, papyrus

I applied a CSS to a model, and after that I was no longer able to work with it, it does not even get rendered. Now every time I try to open it I get the following exception:

```
Java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core.impl.dom.Measure cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.gmfdiag.css.helper.GradientHelper.parseGradient(GradientHelper.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.gmfdiag.css.helper.GradientHelper.parseGradient(GradientHelper.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.gmfdiag.css.helper.GradientHelper.computeGradient(GradientHelper.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.gmfdiag.css.style.impl.CSSShapeStyleDelegate.getCSSGradient(CSSShapeStyleDelegate.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.gmfdiag.css.CSSShapeImpl.getCSSGradient(CSSShapeImpl.java:200)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.gmfdiag.css.CSSShapeImpl.getGradient(CSSShapeImpl.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.editparts.ShapeNodeEditPart.refreshBackgroundColor(ShapeNodeEditPart.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.editparts.ShapeEditPart.refreshVisuals(ShapeEditPart.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.gmfdiag.common.editpart.NodeEditPart.refreshVisuals(NodeEditPart.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.uml.diagram.common.editparts.UMLNodeEditPart.refreshVisuals(UMLNodeEditPart.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.uml.diagram.common.editparts.NamedElementEditPart.refreshVisuals(NamedElementEditPart.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.uml.diagram.common.editparts.ClassifierEditPart.refreshVisuals(ClassifierEditPart.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.refresh(AbstractEditPart.java:725)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.refresh(AbstractGraphicalEditPart.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.editparts.GraphicalEditPart.access$3(GraphicalEditPart.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.editparts.GraphicalEditPart$3.run(GraphicalEditPart.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.emf.transaction.impl.TransactionalEditingDomainImpl.runExclusive(TransactionalEditingDomainImpl.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.editparts.GraphicalEditPart.refresh(GraphicalEditPart.java:851)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.uml.diagram.common.editparts.UMLNodeEditPart.refresh(UMLNodeEditPart.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addNotify(AbstractEditPart.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.addNotify(AbstractGraphicalEditPart.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addChild(AbstractEditPart.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.editparts.GraphicalEditPart.addChild(GraphicalEditPart.java:1319)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.refreshChildren(AbstractEditPart.java:781)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.refresh(AbstractEditPart.java:726)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.refresh(AbstractGraphicalEditPart.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.editparts.GraphicalEditPart.access$3(GraphicalEditPart.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.editparts.GraphicalEditPart$3.run(GraphicalEditPart.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.emf.transaction.impl.TransactionalEditingDomainImpl.runExclusive(TransactionalEditingDomainImpl.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.editparts.GraphicalEditPart.refresh(GraphicalEditPart.java:851)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addNotify(AbstractEditPart.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.addNotify(AbstractGraphicalEditPart.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.editparts.ShapeCompartmentEditPart.addNotify(ShapeCompartmentEditPart.java:783)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addChild(AbstractEditPart.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.editparts.GraphicalEditPart.addChild(GraphicalEditPart.java:1319)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.refreshChildren(AbstractEditPart.java:781)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.refresh(AbstractEditPart.java:726)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.refresh(AbstractGraphicalEditPart.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.editparts.GraphicalEditPart.access$3(GraphicalEditPart.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.editparts.GraphicalEditPart$3.run(GraphicalEditPart.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.emf.transaction.impl.TransactionalEditingDomainImpl.runExclusive(TransactionalEditingDomainImpl.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.editparts.GraphicalEditPart.refresh(GraphicalEditPart.java:851)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.uml.diagram.common.editparts.UMLNodeEditPart.refresh(UMLNodeEditPart.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addNotify(AbstractEditPart.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.addNotify(AbstractGraphicalEditPart.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addChild(AbstractEditPart.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.editparts.GraphicalEditPart.addChild(GraphicalEditPart.java:1319)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.refreshChildren(AbstractEditPart.java:781)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.refresh(AbstractEditPart.java:726)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.refresh(AbstractGraphicalEditPart.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.editparts.GraphicalEditPart.access$3(GraphicalEditPart.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.editparts.GraphicalEditPart$3.run(GraphicalEditPart.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.emf.transaction.impl.TransactionalEditingDomainImpl.runExclusive(TransactionalEditingDomainImpl.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.editparts.GraphicalEditPart.refresh(GraphicalEditPart.java:851)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addNotify(AbstractEditPart.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.addNotify(AbstractGraphicalEditPart.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addChild(AbstractEditPart.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.SimpleRootEditPart.setContents(SimpleRootEditPart.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.gef.ui.parts.AbstractEditPartViewer.setContents(AbstractEditPartViewer.java:617)
    at org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.parts.DiagramGraphicalViewer.setContents(DiagramGraphicalViewer.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.gef.ui.parts.AbstractEditPartViewer.setContents(AbstractEditPartViewer.java:626)
    at org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.parts.DiagramEditor.initializeGraphicalViewerContents(DiagramEditor.java:872)
    at org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.parts.DiagramEditor.initializeGraphicalViewer(DiagramEditor.java:865)
    at org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.parts.DiagramEditorWithFlyOutPalette.initializeGraphicalViewer(DiagramEditorWithFlyOutPalette.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.resources.editor.parts.DiagramDocumentEditor.initializeGraphicalViewer(DiagramDocumentEditor.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.uml.diagram.clazz.part.UMLDiagramEditor.initializeGraphicalViewer(UMLDiagramEditor.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.parts.DiagramEditor.createGraphicalViewer(DiagramEditor.java:807)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.uml.diagram.clazz.UmlClassDiagramForMultiEditor.createGraphicalViewer(UmlClassDiagramForMultiEditor.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.gef.ui.parts.GraphicalEditor.createPartControl(GraphicalEditor.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.parts.DiagramEditor.createPartControl(DiagramEditor.java:1580)
    at org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.parts.DiagramEditorWithFlyOutPalette.createPartControl(DiagramEditorWithFlyOutPalette.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.resources.editor.parts.DiagramDocumentEditor.createPartControl(DiagramDocumentEditor.java:1514)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.uml.diagram.common.part.UmlGmfDiagramEditor.createPartControl(UmlGmfDiagramEditor.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.core.sasheditor.internal.EditorPart.createEditorPartControl(EditorPart.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.core.sasheditor.internal.EditorPart.createPartControl(EditorPart.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.core.sasheditor.internal.TabFolderPart.createChildPart(TabFolderPart.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.core.sasheditor.internal.TabFolderPart.createTabItem(TabFolderPart.java:974)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.core.sasheditor.internal.TabFolderPart.synchronize2(TabFolderPart.java:888)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.core.sasheditor.internal.RootPart.synchronize2(RootPart.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.core.sasheditor.internal.SashWindowsContainer.refreshTabsInternal(SashWindowsContainer.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.core.sasheditor.internal.SashWindowsContainer.refreshTabs(SashWindowsContainer.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.core.sasheditor.internal.SashWindowsContainer.createPartControl(SashWindowsContainer.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.core.sasheditor.editor.AbstractMultiPageSashEditor.createPartControl(AbstractMultiPageSashEditor.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.core.editor.CoreMultiDiagramEditor.createPartControl(CoreMultiDiagramEditor.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPartControl(CompatibilityPart.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor.createPartControl(CompatibilityEditor.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:323)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:877)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:857)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:949)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:633)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:700)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.showTab(StackRenderer.java:1096)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.postProcess(LazyStackRenderer.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:649)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:700)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:645)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$6.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:526)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ElementReferenceRenderer.createWidget(ElementReferenceRenderer.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:949)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:633)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:700)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:645)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:700)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:645)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:700)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:645)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:700)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveRenderer.processContents(PerspectiveRenderer.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:645)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:700)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveStackRenderer.showTab(PerspectiveStackRenderer.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.postProcess(LazyStackRenderer.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveStackRenderer.postProcess(PerspectiveStackRenderer.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:649)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:700)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:645)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:700)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.WBWRenderer.processContents(WBWRenderer.java:676)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:645)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:700)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1042)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
```

The Properties view now only shows the message "Properties are not available", thus I cannot remove the CSS. Is there any hope of saving this model?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The excpetion was being caused by an error in the CSS file. I had a few colours defined:

```
@variables 
{
    myRed: #ff7777;
    myCyan: #55ddff;
}
```

And later on had a style with:

```
[appliedStereotypes~="Stereo"]
{
    gradient: myRed vertical;
    background-color: myCyand;
    bold:true;
    shadow:true;
    elementIcon:true;
    qualifiedNameDepth:full;
}
```

After replacing `myCyand` for `myCyan` the model became functional again.

Unfortunately no elements in the model are getting styled, but that is another question.